# How to Get That Triangulated Low-Poly Look?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I've been doing low-poly models for about a year now cause that's all I can really do. I've always wanted that good triangle looking low poly style. Never knew how to achieve it, Im guessing with modifiers. I'm just unsure, if anyone knows how to do this look please leave a comment. Thanks!

(Example is the game Jalopy)[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for the decimate modifer.
[image: decimate]
Change the shading to Flat, check Triangulate and reduce the ratio to the desired result.

Comment: Thanks a million! :D. I was guessing it was the decimate modifier, just never knew about that triangulate tick mark.